# To sync AudioMemos timestamps with your calendar?

Tags: data-synchronization, calendar

I am trying to find a way how I can sync the timestamps of my recordings to my calendar so I know when I have recorded things. 
I am using the application [AudioMemos](https://itunes.apple.com/ch/app/audio-memos-das-diktiergerat/id338550388?mt=8) at the moment.

How can I sync AudioMemos' recordings to my calendar?

Comment: If you access the audio recordings via remote access, are the timestamps correct?

Comment: Yes, the timestamps are correct. The only thing is to visualise them with your calendar or in some timeline.